How to fix pwa manifest not beinga ble to installed?
So, I have my manifest.json, linked it with the regular method (link:manifest for vscode nerds) and it doesnt work
{

    "name": "Schoology | Learning app",
    "short_name": "Schoology",
    "start_url": "/index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#0362fc",
    "prefer_related_applications": true,
    "description": "Learning App for schools! Schoology helps provide a learning environment with a way to keep assignments in check.",
    "icons": [
                {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-50x50.png",
              "sizes": "50x50",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-65x65.png",
              "sizes": "65x65",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-80x80.png",
              "sizes": "80x80",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-100x100.png",
              "sizes": "100x100",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-115x115.png",
              "sizes": "115x115",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-150x150.png",
              "sizes": "150x150",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-174x174.png",
              "sizes": "174x174",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-193x193.png",
              "sizes": "192x192",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-208x208.png",
              "sizes": "208x208",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-212x212.png",
              "sizes": "212x212",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-240x240.png",
              "sizes": "240x240",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-285x285.png",
              "sizes": "285x285",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-296x296.png",
              "sizes": "296x296",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-300x300.png",
              "sizes": "300x300",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-335x335.png",
              "sizes": "335x335",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-346x346.png",
              "sizes": "346x346",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-386x386.png",
              "sizes": "386x386",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-411x411.png",
              "sizes": "411x411",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-420x420.png",
              "sizes": "420x420",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-450x450.png",
              "sizes": "450x450",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-459x459.png",
              "sizes": "459x459",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-472x472.png",
              "sizes": "512x512",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-768x768.png",
              "sizes": "768x768",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-900x900.png",
              "sizes": "900x900",
              "type": "image/png"
            },
            {
              "src": "./images/schoology-hero-012324-1024x1024.png",
              "sizes": "1024x1024",
              "type": "image/png"
            }
          ]
    

    
}

thats the manifest
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />

is how i linked it
i dont know why its not working, i managed to use mozilla's mdn docs for making the manifest json
then chatgpt for asking WHY ISNT it working, i dont think theres anything else wrong also (the 512, 200 something required is just named differently ok
